# How to get class function from a service that return a model

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, es6-class

I'm having a class (userName) which its properties defined a model (casting from json).
This class has also a simple function that return the full Name:

```
export class userName {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    get fullName() {
     return `${this.firstName} ${this.LastName}`
    }
```

I have a service that return a collection of users:

```
getUsers() : Observable<userName[]>
{
 return this.http.get<userName[]>(<path>);
}
```

Now - I get the collection from the service into the component. When I iterate the collection, I want to get the firstName + LastNamne just like the fullName property does, but it's not part of the model that the service return. Is there a way reaching it without creating my own extension ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Class:**

```
export class userName {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  get fullName() {
    return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
  }

  constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string) {
    Object.assign(this, { firstName, lastName });
  }
}
```

**Service:**

```
getUsers() : Observable<userName[]> {
    return this.http.get<userName[]>(<path>).pipe(map((user: userName) => new userName(user.firstName, user.lastName));
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use map function when you have an object received from the service:

```
getUsers().pipe(    
    map(user => users.map(user => {
       return {
         firstName: user.firstName,
         lastName: user.lastName,
         fullName: user.firstName + user.lastName   
   }))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

*Update userName class to have a constructor:*

```
export class userName {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    get fullName() {
     return `${this.firstName} ${this.LastName}`
    }

    constructor(jsonObject = {}) {
      this.firstName = jsonObject.firstName ? jsonObject.firstName : null;
      this.lastName  = jsonObject.lastName ? jsonObject.lastName : null;
    }
}
```

*Map the http observable response to your object*

```
this.usersService.getUsers()
  .pipe(
    map(res => {
      return res.map((item) => new userName(item));
    })
  )
  .subscribe(users => {
    // console.log(users[0].fullName)
  })
```